# Scientists sets up a delayed encrypted message with a smart contract, containing a world-class discovery. Will he get Nobel prize post-mortem?

Tags: publications, science, awards

It is broadly known that sometimes it happens scientists are not well rewarded during their lives, especially when their work does not fit the modern society needs, or simply if it is well ahead of current time by several generations. Nowadays, there are technologies (such as blockchain, digital signatures, smart contracts) which can guarantee the authorship and serve as a delayed postman, delivering the message, written as a tech report or rather a scientific article, many decades later. Imagine a scientist made a discovery and decided to postpone its publication well beyond his own death.
100 years from now, his work is still a potential breakthrough, and an official authority receives a message signed by him, which automatically unpacks itself, verifies contents and guarantees data authenticity.
Is it eligible for awarding a prize from official scientific community?

Comment: Why would the scientist choose this convoluted method instead of publishing those articles today in a more conventional way? Just because of a weird personal choice, or are there sensitive/forbidden topics involved? Do you have a specific setup in mind?

Comment: You can strip your question of all the details and just ask whether the Nobel Prize can be awarded posthumously.

Comment: @user2705196 question is not about Nobel prize committee specifically; it is about treating such scientist as a great academist

Comment: I'm going to make the totally unsubstantiated claim that is has never been, and is not now possible to be 100 years ahead of the entire world.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no educated person will accept being treated badly or ignored, while still giving such a gift to unthankful people for free

Comment: @ivan OK, that counts as "very weird personal choice" then. :p This scientist sounds more like a movie one than real life. All researchers I know would publish a major breakthrough as soon as possible: by waiting you only risk that someone else makes the same discovery independently and you have to share the credit (do I really want it to be named "the SomeoneElse-Me theorem"?).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni no you won't; according to international scientific rules, if supremacy is proven, then the discovery must be named after the name of scientist who discovered it first; and the tech i wrote about guarantees that; it just says f??? you to all modern people who are not ready to accept it yet

Comment: This is a good example of why we only take “real questions that you are actually facing” — far-fetched hypotheticals are difficult to analyze. Beyond that, there is no “official scientific community” that awards prizes; any given foundation, such as the Nobel, would have to make their own decision.

Comment: @ivan866 Feel free to link to these binding(?) "international scientific rules".

Comment: You posit the problem that many important scientific contributions were perhaps "ahead of their time" and thus went unrewarded. To this you offer a technological solution that, I claim, is redundant. The mathematical work of Évariste Galois was considered "ahead of its time" -- indeed, Siméon Denis Poisson declared his work incomprehensible [ [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89variste_Galois#cite_note-17)]. Yet, here we are two centuries later, using Galois Theory to do sound mathematics. No digital signatures, and no smart contracts.

Answer (score 5):

Since 1974, Nobel Prizes are not awarded posthumously, except in cases where the awardee dies between the announcement and presentation of the award. Different scientific awards may have different rules about posthumous awarding, but a long-dead individual cannot win a Nobel Prize.